# Convert Table to IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to fill the Drop down key and value from database table. What I am doing is

```
        Dictionary<int, string> states = resultSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                             .ToDictionary(row => row.Field<int>(0),
                                                       row => row.Field<string>(1)); 
        //Add the list item 
        states.Add(0, "Select State");
        //Sort the dictionary to set the "0" item at the top
        var sortedStates = (from entry in states orderby entry.Key ascending select entry)
                    .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);

        //Form the SelectListItem
        model.State = from s in sortedStates
                      select new SelectListItem()
                      {
                          Text = s.Value,
                          Value = s.Key.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                      };
```

I am getting the correct output, But I feel it is more elaborated. Is there any best approach to fill the dropdown in MVC.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: p.s., dictionaries are not ordered, so the order you get from the `sortedStates` dictionary will not come out as you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use a `Dictionary` if you want to order it by the key? You could use a `List` and `Insert`:

```
List<SelectListItem> allItems = resultSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
    .OrderBy(r => r.Field<int>(0))
    .Select(r => new SelectListItem { Text = r.Field<string>(1), Value = r.Field<int>(0).ToString() })
    .ToList();

SelectListItem defItem = new SelectListItem { Text = "Select State", Value = "0" };
allItems.Insert(0, defItem);
```

Comment: Simple..straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you overcomplicating things. That might look a bit better:

```
model.State = resultSet.Tables[0]
    .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = x.Id,
            Value = x.StateName
        }
    ).ToList();
```

Just replace `Id` and `StateName` with appropriate column names that you selecting (with `row.Field<int>(0)` and `row.Field<int>(1)`).